# Return Multiple Values from Function with Plyr

Tags: r, function, dataframe, plyr

I'm fairly new to R so take this for what it's worth.

I've written a function that takes 4 arguments and returns a dataframe. The condensed version looks like the following.

```
Advantage <- function(tRos, tTat, cRos, cTat){
  #case 1.1 tRos is lower
  if((tRos > 0 | cRos > 0) & cRos > tRos & cTat < tTat){
    tRosAd <- (cRos - tRos) * cTat * -1
    tTatAd <- (tTat - cTat) * tRos
    r <- c(tRosAd, tTatAd, 1.1)
  }
  else if((tRos > 0 | cRos > 0) & cRos < tRos & cTat > tTat){
    #case 1.2 tRos is higher
    r <- Advantage(cRos, cTat, tRos, tTat)
    r <- r * -1
    r[3] <- 1.2
  }
  r <- data.frame(rosAd = r[1], tatAd = r[2], cat = r[3])
  return(r)
}
```

Then what I need to do is subset the data by year and sic code, and then run the function against that data.

What I've done which is incredibly ugly, incredibly slow, and works but is certainly not the best way to do this is below.

```
bDf <- data.frame()
for (yr in unique(aDf$year)){
  #Subset years
  tmp <- subset(aDf, year == yr)
  for(sc in unique(tmp$sic2)){
    #subset sics
    tmp2 <- subset(tmp, sic2 == sc)
    medRos <- median(tmp2$ros)
    medTat <- median(tmp2$tat)
    for (gvk in unique(tmp2$gvkey)){
      #subset individual gvkeys in the sics
      tmp3 <- subset(tmp2, gvk == gvkey)
      x <- Advantage(tmp3$ros, tmp3$tat, medRos, medTat)
      x <- cbind(tmp3, x)
      bDf <- rbind(bDf, x)
    }
  }
}
```

I originally had the function return a list and then tried to apply the function to the data frame and return the list, but it kept chopping off the last column.

It looked something like the following:

```
outPut <- Advantage(tmp2$ros, tmp2$tat, median(tmp2$ros), median(tmp2$tat))
```

Any advice on how to correct my ugly code would be appreciated. I have a feeling that this could be one line in the plyr package, but I have yet to figure it out.

The data looks like the following:

```
      gvkey year   at   ni sic sales        roa        ros       tat sic2
17857  1266 1966 5.21 0.06 100  1.06 0.01151631 0.05660377 0.2034549   10
17858  1266 1967 5.78 0.31 100  1.28 0.05363322 0.24218750 0.2214533   10
17859  1266 1968 6.54 0.79 100  1.80 0.12079511 0.43888889 0.2752294   10
17860  1266 1969 6.77 0.22 100  1.88 0.03249631 0.11702128 0.2776957   10
17861  1266 1970 8.57 0.15 100  2.42 0.01750292 0.06198347 0.2823804   10
17862  1266 1971 9.02 0.18 100  3.09 0.01995565 0.05825243 0.3425721   10
```

Each gvkey corresponds to a unique company. I am taking the median ros & tat from each sector (sic2) for each year and comparing each company within that sector to the median for that sector in a given year.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data to work with... as it stands, I assume each subset is 1 or more rows and thus your `Advantage` function's `if` statement will probably not do what you think it will...

Comment: Sure it is Return on Sales and Asset Turnover data for every publicly traded company for the last 45 years. gvkeys represent unique companies.

Comment: Why don't you try to recreate your problem on a smaller scale. Obviously, speed probably won't be a problem at that point, but at least others would be able to see clear example of input and desired output and be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer two loops can be replaced with one `ddply` call and the inner one with a second one. I retained the `tmp2` and `tmp3` names to show what they corresponded to in your original code.

```
library("plyr")
bDf <- ddply(aDf, .(year, sic2), function(tmp2) {
  medRos <- median(tmp2$ros)
  medTat <- median(tmp2$tat)
  ddply(tmp2, .(gvkey), function(tmp3) {
    Advantage(tmp3$ros, tmp3$tat, medRos, medTat)
  })
})
```

There are problems in your `Advantage` function: in case 1.2, `Advantage` returns a `data.frame`, but the rest of the code in that block treats it as though it returns a vector. Also, the two cases don't cover all possibilities (for example, with the example data you gave, neither case criteria is satisfied). If you get your `Advantage` function working (and returning a data.frame with the appropriate columns), then this gives the way to loop over the subsets you wanted.